# How to extract key and value of greatest value in Hive map?

Tags: hive

I have in Hive a field which contains a map that looks like this: 
`{"258":0.10075276284486512,"259":0.00093852142318649,"262":0.015979321337627,"264":0.0020453444772401,"265":0.024689771044731,"268":0.018837925051338,"274":0.011282124863882}`

I would like to extract the key [and value if possible] of this map of the greatest value for each row. In this case, the ideal function would look like this:

`select max_val(col)
from table`

Output:

```
 max_val
 "258"
 "165"
 "204"
```

Answer (score 0):

`explode` the `map` column and then use a ranking function like `rank` to order the values as required and get first such row. (This assumes there is a way to identify a row with any other column than the `map`, `id` in the query shown below.)

```
select id,k,v
from (select id,k,v,rank() over(partition by id order by v desc) as rnum
      from tbl
      lateral view explode(mapCol) t as k,v
     ) t
where rnum=1
```